# WebDriver finding by class name

Tags: python, selenium, class, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to find information on a webpage using the class attribute and selenium WeDriver. I am looking to print out the **`6 + 8`** in the following HTML:

```
<a href="/#/basic-math-pre-algebra/16869" class="question-link"><b>6 + 8</b> = </a>
```

I am searching by class name, and I have tried XPATH as well. The XPATH is:

```
//*[@id="question-link"]
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url_rice = 'http://freerice.com/#/basic-math-pre-algebra/16869'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://freerice.com/#/basic-math-pre-algebra/16869')

def question():
    print(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("question-link"))

question()

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question you must not restrict your tests to **class** *attribute* only. At times *CSS-SELECTOR* are found to be better performing where as at times *XPATH* comes handy.

As per the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) the text **6 + 8** is within the *ancestor node* having the *class* attribute as **question-link** which have a *descendent node* as `<b>` which actually contains the desired text. So using either a *CSS-SELECTOR* or a *XPATH* you need to identify the `<b>` node.

To extract the information, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* and you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://freerice.com/#/basic-math-pre-algebra/16869')
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.block-means-vocab div#question-title b"))).text)
```

Note: As per best practices always open the browser in **maximized** mode and *disabling* the **infobars** and **extensions**

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain this a little more?

Comment: @MassimoDaul Checkout my answer update and let me know if you have any question